# Подскажите, как без установки оперативной памяти узнать производителя чипов

Tags: пк

Подскажите, как без установки оперативной памяти узнать производителя чипов.
Купил память, материнки пока нет, хотелось бы узнать по коробке\этикетке, но там нигде не нашел, может кто подскажет как это можно ещё сделать ? Память Gskill

---

Comment: Ну, на самих чипах должно быть написано, наверное?

Comment: 1. Посмотреть на чипах. 2. Если есть радиатор - снять радиатор и выполнить первый пункт. Есть еще вариант с гаданием на кофейной гуще, но там рандом